# Android XMl Binding - Simpleframework

Tags: java, android, xml, binding

I'm trying to bind a XML to POJOs using [Simpleframework](http://www.simpleframework.org/) but it doesn't work correctly and I can't spot the mistake. This structure worked perfectly with JAXB, I just changed the annotations to Simpleframework's. Maybe the mistake is in the `List<Track>` thing but I'm not able to figure it out.

Message.toString writes this (header is mapped correctly):

```
Message [body=Body [trackList=TrackList [tracks=[Track [trackId=null, trackMbid=null, trackLength=null, lyricsId=null, instrumental=null, subtitleId=null, trackName=null, albumName=null, albumId=null, artistId=null, albumCoverart=null, artistMbid=null, artistName=null], Track [trackId=null, trackMbid=null, trackLength=null, lyricsId=null, instrumental=null, subtitleId=null, trackName=null, albumName=null, albumId=null, artistId=null, albumCoverart=null, artistMbid=null, artistName=null], Track [trackId=null, trackMbid=null, trackLength=null, lyricsId=null, instrumental=null, subtitleId=null, trackName=null, albumName=null, albumId=null, artistId=null, albumCoverart=null, artistMbid=null, artistName=null], Track [trackId=null, trackMbid=null, trackLength=null, lyricsId=null, instrumental=null, subtitleId=null, trackName=null, albumName=null, albumId=null, artistId=null, albumCoverart=null, artistMbid=null, artistName=null], Track [trackId=null, trackMbid=null, trackLength=null, lyricsId=null, instrumental=null, subtitleId=null, trackName=null, albumName=null, albumId=null, artistId=null, albumCoverart=null, artistMbid=null, artistName=null], Track [trackId=null, trackMbid=null, trackLength=null, lyricsId=null, instrumental=null, subtitleId=null, trackName=null, albumName=null, albumId=null, artistId=null, albumCoverart=null, artistMbid=null, artistName=null], Track [trackId=null, trackMbid=null, trackLength=null, lyricsId=null, instrumental=null, subtitleId=null, trackName=null, albumName=null, albumId=null, artistId=null, albumCoverart=null, artistMbid=null, artistName=null], Track [trackId=null, trackMbid=null, trackLength=null, lyricsId=null, instrumental=null, subtitleId=null, trackName=null, albumName=null, albumId=null, artistId=null, albumCoverart=null, artistMbid=null, artistName=null], Track [trackId=null, trackMbid=null, trackLength=null, lyricsId=null, instrumental=null, subtitleId=null, trackName=null, albumName=null, albumId=null, artistId=null, albumCoverart=null, artistMbid=null, artistName=null], Track [trackId=null, trackMbid=null, trackLength=null, lyricsId=null, instrumental=null, subtitleId=null, trackName=null, albumName=null, albumId=null, artistId=null, albumCoverart=null, artistMbid=null, artistName=null], Track [trackId=null, trackMbid=null, trackLength=null, lyricsId=null, instrumental=null, subtitleId=null, trackName=null, albumName=null, albumId=null, artistId=null, albumCoverart=null, artistMbid=null, artistName=null], Track [trackId=null, trackMbid=null, trackLength=null, lyricsId=null, instrumental=null, subtitleId=null, trackName=null, albumName=null, albumId=null, artistId=null, albumCoverart=null, artistMbid=null, artistName=null], Track [trackId=null, trackMbid=null, trackLength=null, lyricsId=null, instrumental=null, subtitleId=null, trackName=null, albumName=null, albumId=null, artistId=null, albumCoverart=null, artistMbid=null, artistName=null]]]], header=Header [statusCode=200, executeTime=0.0075960159301758, available=1]]
```

This is the incomming XML:

```
<message>
<header>
    <status_code>200</status_code>
    <execute_time>0.0075960159301758</execute_time>
    <available>1</available>
</header>
<body>
    <track_list>
        <track>
            <track_id>4110618</track_id>
            <track_mbid>888d13a8-5bbb-44d8-b3c9-5c3812020110</track_mbid>
            <track_length>0</track_length>
            <lyrics_id>6283932</lyrics_id>
            <instrumental>0</instrumental>
            <subtitle_id>0</subtitle_id>
            <track_name>Stan</track_name>
            <album_name>How to Be an MC, Volume 13 (Eminem Instrumentals)</album_name>
            <album_id>10558107</album_id>
            <artist_id>426</artist_id>
            <album_coverart_100x100>http://api.musixmatch.com/albumcover/10558107.jpg</album_coverart_100x100>
            <artist_mbid>b95ce3ff-3d05-4e87-9e01-c97b66af13d4</artist_mbid>
            <artist_name>Eminem</artist_name>
        </track>
    </track_list>
</body>
```

And these are the classes I'm using:

```
package org.lyrics.xml.binding.track;

import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

@Root(name = "message")
public class Message {

@Element(name = "header", required = false)
public Header header;
@Element(name = "body", required = false)
public Body body;

public Body getBody() {
    return body;
}

public void setBody(Body body) {
    this.body = body;
}

public Header getHeader() {
    return header;
}

public void setHeader(Header header) {
    this.header = header;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Message [body=" + body + ", header=" + header + "]";
}

}
```

---

```
package org.lyrics.xml.binding.track;

import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;

public class Header {

@Element(name = "status_code", required = false)
public String statusCode;
@Element(name = "execute_time", required = false)
public String executeTime;
@Element(name = "available", required = false)
public String available;

public String getStatusCode() {
    return statusCode;
}

public void setStatusCode(String statusCode) {
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
}

public String getExecuteTime() {
    return executeTime;
}

public void setExecuteTime(String executeTime) {
    this.executeTime = executeTime;
}

public String getAvailable() {
    return available;
}

public void setAvailable(String available) {
    this.available = available;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Header [statusCode=" + statusCode + ", executeTime="
            + executeTime + ", available=" + available + "]";
}

}
```

---

```
package org.lyrics.xml.binding.track;

import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;

public class Body {

@Element(name = "track_list", required = false)
public TrackList trackList;

public TrackList getTrackList() {
    return trackList;
}

public void setTrackList(TrackList trackList) {
    this.trackList = trackList;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Body [trackList=" + trackList + "]";
}

}
```

---

```
package org.lyrics.xml.binding.track;

import java.util.List;

import org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList;

public class TrackList {

@ElementList(name = "track", required = false)
public List<Track> tracks;

public List<Track> getTracks() {
    return tracks;
}

public void setTracks(List<Track> tracks) {
    this.tracks = tracks;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "TrackList [tracks=" + tracks + "]";
}

}
```

---

```
package org.lyrics.xml.binding.track;

import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

@Root(name = "track")
public class Track {

@Element(name="track_id", required = false)
public String trackId;

@Element(name="track_mbid", required = false)
public String trackMbid;

@Element(name="track_length", required = false)
public String trackLength;

@Element(name="lyrics_id", required = false)
public String lyricsId;

@Element(name="instrumental", required = false)
public String instrumental;

@Element(name="subtitle_id", required = false)
public String subtitleId;

@Element(name="track_name", required = false)
public String trackName;

@Element(name="album_name", required = false)
public String albumName;

@Element(name="album_id", required = false)
public String albumId;

@Element(name="artist_id", required = false)
public String artistId;

@Element(name="album_coverart_100x100", required = false)
public String albumCoverart;

@Element(name="artist_mbid", required = false)
public String artistMbid;

@Element(name="artist_name", required = false)
public String artistName;

public String getTrackId() {
    return trackId;
}

public void setTrackId(String trackId) {
    this.trackId = trackId;
}

public String getTrackMbid() {
    return trackMbid;
}

public void setTrackMbid(String trackMbid) {
    this.trackMbid = trackMbid;
}

public String getTrackLength() {
    return trackLength;
}

public void setTrackLength(String trackLength) {
    this.trackLength = trackLength;
}

public String getLyricsId() {
    return lyricsId;
}

public void setLyricsId(String lyricsId) {
    this.lyricsId = lyricsId;
}

public String getInstrumental() {
    return instrumental;
}

public void setInstrumental(String instrumental) {
    this.instrumental = instrumental;
}

public String getSubtitleId() {
    return subtitleId;
}

public void setSubtitleId(String subtitleId) {
    this.subtitleId = subtitleId;
}

public String getTrackName() {
    return trackName;
}

public void setTrackName(String trackName) {
    this.trackName = trackName;
}

public String getAlbumName() {
    return albumName;
}

public void setAlbumName(String albumName) {
    this.albumName = albumName;
}

public String getAlbumId() {
    return albumId;
}

public void setAlbumId(String albumId) {
    this.albumId = albumId;
}

public String getArtistId() {
    return artistId;
}

public void setArtistId(String artistId) {
    this.artistId = artistId;
}

public String getAlbumCoverart() {
    return albumCoverart;
}

public void setAlbumCoverart(String albumCoverart) {
    this.albumCoverart = albumCoverart;
}

public String getArtistMbid() {
    return artistMbid;
}

public void setArtistMbid(String artistMbid) {
    this.artistMbid = artistMbid;
}

public String getArtistName() {
    return artistName;
}

public void setArtistName(String artistName) {
    this.artistName = artistName;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Track [trackId=" + trackId + ", trackMbid=" + trackMbid
            + ", trackLength=" + trackLength + ", lyricsId=" + lyricsId
            + ", instrumental=" + instrumental + ", subtitleId="
            + subtitleId + ", trackName=" + trackName + ", albumName="
            + albumName + ", albumId=" + albumId + ", artistId=" + artistId
            + ", albumCoverart=" + albumCoverart + ", artistMbid="
            + artistMbid + ", artistName=" + artistName + "]";
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The attribute `inline=true` must be here:

```
@ElementList(name = "track", required = false)
public List<Track> tracks;
```